# How do I represent a calculated complex number in python?

Tags: python, math

The results of the calculation may produce complex numbers, but the following code yields results that do not represent them. How should I get the complex number result?

For example when `a=1, b=8, c=16 d=10` I think the result should be `x1=-5.365 x2=-1.317+0.358i x3=-1.3173-0.358i`, but I get `x1=-5.365 x2=-1.1121 x3=-3.8074`, the result is missing the imaginary part.

```py
import math
import numpy as np

class Shengjin:
    def compute_shengjin(self,a,b,c,d):
        A,B,C=self.discriminant_repeated_root(a,b,c,d)
        if A==0 and B==0:
            X_1=-b/3*a
            X_2=-c/b
            X_3=-3*d/c
        else:
            derta=self.discriminant_final(A,B,C)
            if derta>0:
                Y_1=A*b+3*a*((-B+math.sqrt((B**2)-4*A*C))/2)
                Y_2 = A * b + 3 * a * ((-B - math.sqrt((B ** 2) - 4 * A * C)) / 2)
                X_1=(-b-(np.cbrt(Y_1)+np.cbrt(Y_2)))/(3*a)
                X_2=(-b+0.5*(np.cbrt(Y_1)+np.cbrt(Y_2))+(math.sqrt(3)/2)*np.cbrt(Y_1)-np.cbrt(Y_2))/(3*a)
                X_3=(-b+0.5*(np.cbrt(Y_1)+np.cbrt(Y_2))-(math.sqrt(3)/2)*np.cbrt(Y_1)-np.cbrt(Y_2))/(3*a)
            elif derta==0:
                K=B/A
                X_1=-b/a+K
                X_2=X_3=-K/2
            else:
                T=(2*A*b-3*a*B)/(2*math.sqrt(A**3))
                theta=math.acos(T)
                X_1=(-b-2*math.sqrt(A)*math.cos(theta/3))/(3*a)
                X_2=(-b+math.sqrt(A)*(math.cos(theta/3)+math.sqrt(3)*math.sin(theta/3)))/(3*a)
                X_3 = (-b + math.sqrt(A) * (math.cos(theta / 3) - math.sqrt(3) * math.sin(theta / 3))) / (3 * a)
        return X_1,X_2,X_3

    @staticmethod
    def discriminant_repeated_root(a,b,c,d):
        A = b ** 2 - 3 * a * c
        B = b * c - 9 * a * d
        C = c ** 2 - 3 * b * d
        return A, B, C

    @staticmethod
    def discriminant_final(A,B,C):
        derta=B**2-4*A*C
        return derta

print( Shengjin().compute_shengjin(a=1, b=8, c=16, d=10) )
# (-5.365230013414096, -1.1121836428103815, -3.8074674147392535)
# should be: 
## x1=-5.365, x2=-1.317+0.358j, x3=-1.3173-0.358j
```

Comment: What do you mean? If the code doesn't produce complex results this may mean that it was incorrectly translated from mathematical formulas.

Comment: @Michael Butscher For example when a=1, b=8, c=16 d=10 I think the result should be x1=-5.365 x2=-1.317+0.358i x3=-1.3173-0.358i, but I get x1=-5.365 x2=-1.1121 x3=-3.8074

Comment: unless you start with a complex number (even if the imaginary component is zero) none of the functions will convert a float to a complex. you should either get a `ValueError` from the `math` module or `nan` from `numpy`, which may get swallowed in other calculations.

Comment: Your code never tries to build a complex number... BTW `math.sqrt(-1)` correctly throws a ValueError but `(-1)**(1/2)` does produce a complex number: `(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)`... But it does not work with `np.float64` numbers so better to explicitely use complex numbers...

Comment: You should use the `cmath` module from the standard library instead of `math` if you want to return complex numbers.

Comment: We don't know what you're doing, so we don't know why you expect complex numbers. It's clear that your code won't produce complex numbers the way it's written right now. I see in your code `if derta>0: ... elif derta==0: ... else: ...`. I assume you want the `else` part to produce complex numbers? You can write complex numbers in python using symbol `j`: for instance `(-b - 1j * math.sqrt(derta)) / (2 * a)` would be a complex number.

Comment: I reconfirmed the formula and I found that I had lost the imaginary number part of the formula, so the code part also created an omission, and now I filled in the code and the problem was solved. Thank you all for your reminders and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Shengjin:
    def compute(self, a, b, c, d):
        A, B, C = self.discriminant_param(a, b, c, d)
        if A == 0 and B == 0:
            X_1 = -b / 3 * a
            X_2 = -c / b
            X_3 = -3 * d / c
        else:
            delta = self.discriminant(A, B, C)
            if delta > 0:
                Y_1 = A * b + 3 * a * ((-B + np.sqrt((B ** 2) - 4 * A * C)) / 2)
                Y_2 = A * b + 3 * a * ((-B - np.sqrt((B ** 2) - 4 * A * C)) / 2)
                X_1 = (-b - (np.cbrt(Y_1) + np.cbrt(Y_2))) / (3 * a)
                real = (-2 * b + np.cbrt(Y_1) + np.cbrt(Y_2)) / (6 * a)
                imaginary = ((np.sqrt(3) * (np.cbrt(Y_1) - np.cbrt(Y_2))) / (6 * a)) * 1j
                X_2 = real + imaginary
                X_3 = real - imaginary
            elif delta == 0:
                K = B / A
                X_1 = -b / a + K
                X_2 = X_3 = -K / 2
            else:
                T = (2 * A * b - 3 * a * B) / (2 * np.sqrt(A ** 3))
                theta = np.arccos(T)
                X_1 = (-b - 2 * np.sqrt(A) * np.cos(theta / 3)) / (3 * a)
                X_2 = (-b + np.sqrt(A) * (np.cos(theta / 3) + np.sqrt(3) * np.sin(theta / 3))) / (3 * a)
                X_3 = (-b + np.sqrt(A) * (np.cos(theta / 3) - np.sqrt(3) * np.sin(theta / 3))) / (3 * a)
        return X_1, X_2, X_3

    @staticmethod
    def discriminant_param(a, b, c, d):
        A = b ** 2 - 3 * a * c
        B = b * c - 9 * a * d
        C = c ** 2 - 3 * b * d
        return A, B, C

    @staticmethod
    def discriminant(A, B, C):
        delta = B ** 2 - 4 * A * C
        return delta


    # When a, b, c, d = 1, 8, 16, 10 we have:
    # x1:-5.365230013414098 x2:(-1.3173849932929513+0.3582593599240431j) x3:(-1.3173849932929513-0.3582593599240431j)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).